# How to parse inner JSON object using Gson in Android

Tags: android, json, gson

I need to parse this json,can any one help me to do this?

here I am able to data object using gson not able to parse this VehicleConfig* object ??? Using POJO class

Comment: create a separate pojo for your inner json object.

Comment: ... and use composition to place the inner pojo object into the outer one

Comment: Since the POJO you are deserializing into isn't working, show that?a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: @Kuldeep Singh see my updated answer.

Comment: I don't want to create a new POJO Class for the same, till now I am able to parse my Data object, here I am creating a POJO class inside it I am creating a Class here I am creating setter and getter methods, But dnt know how to parse for "VehicleConfig".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON using GSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465318/how-to-parse-json-using-gson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow these steps

Step 1.

Create a new variable like that

```
public class Data {

      // your rest variables

      @SerializedName("VehicleConfig")
      @Expose
      private VehicleConfig vehicleConfig;

      // getter & setter method

      public void setVehicleImage(Integer vehicleImage) {
           this.vehicleImage = vehicleImage;
      }

      public VehicleConfig getVehicleConfig() {
              return vehicleConfig;
      }

 }
```

Step 2.

Create a new class with "VehicleConfig" name.

```
public class VehicleConfig {

       @SerializedName("Id")
       @Expose
       private Integer id;
       @SerializedName("Title")
       @Expose
       private String title;
       @SerializedName("RegularSeats")
       @Expose
       private Integer regularSeats;
       @SerializedName("RegularWheelChairs")
       @Expose
       private Integer regularWheelChairs;
       @SerializedName("BariatricsWheelChair")
       @Expose
       private Integer bariatricsWheelChair;

       public Integer getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public void setId(Integer id) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public String getTitle() {
           return title;
       }

       public void setTitle(String title) {
           this.title = title;
       }

       public Integer getRegularSeats() {
           return regularSeats;
       }

       public void setRegularSeats(Integer regularSeats) {
           this.regularSeats = regularSeats;
       }

       public Integer getRegularWheelChairs() {
           return regularWheelChairs;
       }

       public void setRegularWheelChairs(Integer regularWheelChairs) {
           this.regularWheelChairs = regularWheelChairs;
       }

       public Integer getBariatricsWheelChair() {
           return bariatricsWheelChair;
       }

       public void setBariatricsWheelChair(Integer bariatricsWheelChair) {
           this.bariatricsWheelChair = bariatricsWheelChair;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
       }
  }
```

Step 3.

Now you can read it easily like

```
Data data = // your values

VehicleConfig vehicleConfig = data.getVehicleConfig();

String title = vehicleConfig.getTitle();
Integer id = vehicleConfig.getId();
// you can read rest values
```

Comment: remove the copyright code from the bottom of your snippet

Comment: I love when people paste result of http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ as answer ... you have enough reputation to mark this question as duplicate instead ansering

Comment: I was about to comment that don't start the downvoting war with me as I haven't done that

Comment: @Selvin Removed copied  data & now its customised data, You can upvote it again.

Comment: @VivekMishra hahah It's ok bro. Thanks

Comment: @Selvin I can mark it duplicate but he tried GSON andhe's having only 1 issue to read particular values. Thats why i gave answer.

Comment: also your formatting is wrong too. Different classes should be put in different code blocks

Comment: @KuldeepSingh Done bro.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(vehicleConfigString);
    return gson.fromJson(jsonElement,objectType);
```

Here vehicleConfigString is the string version of the VehicleConfig node and object type is the POJO_CLASS_NAME.class variable.